# MATLAB newlin function

Tags: matlab, nntool

This is simple example for intro to Neural Network toolbox. However, I cannot run it without error. Do you have any suggestions?

Note: I have Neural Network toolbox and I can see inside the `newlin` function by edit!

```
>> P1 = {0 -1 1 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1};
>> T1 = {0 -1 0 2 1 -1 0 1 0 1};
>> net = newlin(P1,T1,[0 1],0.01);
??? Undefined function or method 'newlin' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

Comment: Maybe clean your environment first in case newlin is defined somewhere else? `close all; clear all; path(pathdef); clc;`. Then explicitly add to your path `newlin.m`.

Comment: I already have done it before asking this question here like this :

Comment: close all;clear all;path(pathdef); clc; P1 = {0 -1 1 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1};
       T1 = {0 -1 0 2 1 -1 0 1 0 1};
 
       net = newlin(P1,T1,[0 1],0.01);

Comment: If you do `newlin()` what does it return?

Comment: Do I need to add explicitly newlin.m because when i wrote on command prompt >edit newlin i can see the inside of function!

Comment: >> newlin()
??? Undefined function or variable 'newlin'.

Comment: ok so it doesn't see `newlin.m`, otherwise the error message would have been `Error using newlin (line 92). Not enough input arguments.`. Try adding `newlin.m` manually.

Comment: Franck I know to add folder directory by edit pathdef however how can i add .m file to folder ? (Note the folder which newlin is inside is already in the pathdef.m, I saw it!)

Comment: Yep sorry I meant adding the folder indeed. To make sure the path is set when you run the script, you can use `addpath` at the beginning of it. How about adding a `testme.m` file along with `newlin.m` and try calling `testme`?

Comment: I think we are going on the wrong path :( Because i have tried this license checkout Neural_Network_Toolbox and there isnot license probably this is the reason i think however i have a license for my entire matlab version

Comment: Read my edit, newlin does not accept cell inputs.

Comment: Yep maybe there is a conflict with http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/adaptive-linear-network-architecture.html indeed. The documentation seems to be self-contradictory.

Comment: Also i have tried your way like this i changed current folder to newlin directory as C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork. Still cannot run this function and the same problems. So i think it isnot related with path problem. Are u agree with me ?

Comment: Yep agree, now the only thing I can think of is what Oleg said in his answer.

Comment: When you changed current folder to newlin directory as C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork, what does newlin() return?

Comment: No because i have found Oleg's suggestion before and i have tried it before asking this question here!

Comment: I think it is related with license but i cannot be sure.                    >> license checkout Neural_Network_Toolbox
License checkout failed.
License Manager Error -101
All licenses are reserved for others.
 The system administrator has reserved all the licenses for others.
 Reservations are made in the options file. The license server system must
 be restarted for options file changes to take effect.

Troubleshoot this issue by visiting: 
http://www.mathworks.com/support/lme/R2010a/101

Diagnostic Information:
Feature: Neural_Network_Toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that you have the Neural Network Toolbox installed with:

```
ver nnet
```

**EDIT**

I see now, `newlin()` does NOT accept cell array inputs, i.e. curly braces `{ }`, use square brackets for concatenation, i.e. `[ ]`,  to get vectors of type `double`:

```
 P1 = [0 -1 1 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1];
 T1 = [0 -1 0 2 1 -1 0 1 0 1];
```

Comment: Read Note insdie the question!

Comment: Yes, but does the command return the version or not? If not, it might be license problems and you would need to edit the configs with FLEXnet lm.

Comment: >> ver nnet
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MATLAB Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a)
MATLAB License Number: 186994
Operating System: Microsoft Windows 7 Version 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_12-b04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Neural Network Toolbox                                Version 6.0.4      (R2010a)

Comment: I have tried this before already this is not the case! >> P1 = [0 -1 1 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1];
>> T1 = [0 -1 0 2 1 -1 0 1 0 1];
>> net = newlin([-1 1],1,[0 1]);
??? Undefined function or method 'newlin' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Comment: Try to run `which newlin -all`, what do you get?

Comment: yeah exactly there is no license :(           C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\nnet\nnet\nnnetwork\newlin.m  % Has no license available

Comment: Try to run `rehash toolboxcache` then `which newlin -all`. Also, do you happen to have other newlins? Or, did you add files to the NN toolbox?

Comment: >> rehash toolboxcache
>> newlin -all
??? Undefined function or method 'newlin' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Comment: What you mean other newlins? I didnt add any files or any lines to NN because it is my first example in NN toolbox.